# How to understand which thread is making a new variable during debugging?

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

I'm studying Java and I'm working on a very simple code that start 3 threads.
Is composed by 3 classes

- `TxColor` change the color to the text printed in console from the threads
- `ThNew` build and run the threads
- `ThRandy` start the threads (main function)

`TxColor`

```
/*
    to color the output text
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


class TxColor {

    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
    public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
    public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";

    private static Random r = new Random();

    private static String oldpick = "null";

    private static ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ANSI_RESET,ANSI_BLACK,ANSI_RED,ANSI_GREEN,ANSI_BLUE,ANSI_PURPLE,ANSI_CYAN));


    static ArrayList<String> getCList(){
        return l;
    }

    // choose a random color thread
    static String colPick(){

        String col = "null";
        int count = 0;
        do{
            count++;
            int n = r.nextInt(l.size());
            col = getCList().get(n);
        }while (col==oldpick && count<10);
        count = 0;
        oldpick=col;
        return col;
    }
}
```

`ThNew`

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ThNew extends Thread {

    private String name = "standard";



    ThNew(String name){
        this.name = name;

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(TxColor.colPick()+"Thread " + name + " started");
    }

}
```

`ThRandy`

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ThRandy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random r = new Random();

        ThNew th1 = new ThNew("Mario");
        ThNew th2 = new ThNew("Giorgio");
        ThNew th3 = new ThNew("Andrea");
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th3.start();

    }

}
```

In the module `colPick()` I use the variable count to be sure 100% the code end exiting the loop in case is not able to pick a random color different from the previous one.
If you notice the `count` variable is not static, so every thread has is own count variable.
I didn't use synchronize to reproduce the issue I will describe you.

When I debug using Intellij https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ I have this screen

[image]

I don't know if is common also in Eclipse or any other IDE, but as you can see in the picture I cannot recognize the `int count` variable of one thread from another. I only notice to have more than one `count` because the debug jump forward and back again in the code due to the presence of multiple thread.

There is a way to understand which thread is creating that specific count variable?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Sido note : `col==oldpick` this is not how you would like to compare Strings in Java (in almost all cases). Use `equals` instead.

Comment: And also keep in mind that `col` is a local variable so every thread will have it's own `count` when it invokes `colPick` method.

Comment: @michalk in this case it is still correct, since `oldpick` will be an instance from the list or the string literal `"null"`.

Comment: Also note that `static` isn't directly related to threads but rather, whether a variable exists only once globally or once per object instance of the declaring class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I wish to contribute with my help.

You just open the curtain menu as shown in the picture and you can see every thread with their own variables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach to this problem is to rearrange the list: pick a random element in the list, swap it with the last element, and always return the last element in the list:

```
static int e = l.size(); // added

static synchronized String colPick(){
    int n = r.nextInt(e);
    int last = l.size() - 1;
    Collections.swap(l, n, last);
    e = last;
    return l.get(last);
}
```

The way this works is a bit subtle.

- Initially, `e`, the range of random numbers you can pick, is the size of the list, so this allows any colour to be picked first time.
- The picked element is then swapped with the element at the end of the list
- `e` is then updated to be one less than the size of the list: this means that, on the next iteration, the last element of the list can't be picked. As such, it is guaranteed that the same element can't be picked twice in a row (unless there are two equal elements).

Note that this *has* to be synchronized for two reasons:

1. You aren't using a thread-safe random class, such as `ThreadSafeRandom`.
2. The swapping and reading of the last item, and the update to `e`, has to be done atomically.